# How to parse JSON from Url and named array

Tags: php, jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON string from a url with a named array.
    Ex.

```
{
    "Attendees": [{
        "user_id": "123",
        "first_name": "Jim",
        "last_name": "Bill",
        "email": "jsfbsjkd@aim.com",
        "title": "Admin",
        "business_unit": "",
        "area": ""
    }]
}
```

i've tired this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $.getJSON('http://localhost/testJSON/json.php', function(data){
  alert(data.user_id); // 1 });
});
```

but it's creating `Object Object`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use console.log(data)

Comment: How about data.Attendees[0].user_id ?

Comment: `data.Attendees[0].user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of alert(), try this:

```
console.log(data.Attendees[0].user_id);
```

Then using developer tools in Chrome (or another developer friendly browser), check the console for the result here.

Comment: Please let me know if my solution resolved your question, or if you need any more help with it :)